# turn off the old dialog before open the new one java swing

Tags: java, swing, notepad

anyone help me please , i create a notepad by java-swing . But i have a problem . Anytime i using a action-event (replace , find ) and the program show it on the screen , and i using action-event again it show another on the screen but doesn't turn off the old one .

```
private void replaceController(MainForm mainForm) {
    mainForm.getReplace().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ReplaceForm replaceForm = new ReplaceForm(mainForm, false);
            replaceForm.setVisible(true);
            replaceForm.getBtnReplace().setEnabled(false);
            replaceForm.getBtnReplaceAll().setEnabled(false);



            ReplaceController replaceController = new ReplaceController();
            replaceController.checkEmptyReplace(replaceForm);
            replaceController.replace(mainForm, replaceForm);
            replaceController.f(mainForm, replaceForm);
            replaceController.replaceAll(mainForm, replaceForm);
            replaceController.cancelReplace(replaceForm);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: help me please help me pleasehelp me pleasehelp me please

Comment: It does not _turn off the old one_  just because you have not programmed it to do so. You create new instance of Frame each time the action is called and do not bother of the ones that do already exist to the moment. You should revise your program logic at the place.

Comment: Check [EventObject#getSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()), you can then do something like `JButton myClickedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();JFrame myFirstFrame = (JFrame) myClickedButton.getParent(); myFirstFrame.dispose()` (just find a way to get the container of the clicked button and dispose the frame). Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't create your dialog each time you try to search, but only make it visible instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to [default close operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) you apply to your top-level JFrame or JDialog.

If you want the frame just to hide and not to be disposed use `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`. And set it to `visible` when you want it to shown on the screen again. This means you need the only instance of the frame.

If you want it to be disposed (looks like that, as here you construct new one each time the action called), use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`. Then each time user closes the frame it will be destroyed.